# Gmail auth firebase not working in release flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, bloc

I implemented google sign-in and it works really fine with `debug mode` but the moment I build the release version of my web app:

`flutter web --release`

You may check at https://decentralpeople.web.app/

It doesn't work. Plus, it doesn't show any error logs when I used:

`flutter run -d edge --release`

#### Release Logs

No error no nothing is being shown

[image]

#### Code (BloC Implementation)

**Cubit**

```dart
 Future<void> googleSignIn() async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      socialAuthState: const SocialAuthLoading(),
    ));
    try {
      final data = await repo.googleSignIn();
      repo.isLoggedIn = true;
      emit(state.copyWith(
        socialAuthState: SocialAuthSuccess(data: data),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        socialAuthState: SocialAuthFailed(message: e.toString()),
      ));
    }
  }
```

**Data provider**

```dart
static Future<UserData> googleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final creds = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(creds);

      final _userData = {
        "fullName": googleUser.displayName,
        "email": googleUser.email,
        "photo": googleUser.photoUrl,
        "provider": "google",
      };

      await _hive.put('user', _userData);

      return UserData.fromMap(_userData);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }
  }
```

**Call at Front-end**

```dart
CustomButton(
  btnWidth: Responsive.isDesktop(context)
      ? _size.width * 0.1
      : _size.width * 0.15,
  btnHeight: 45.5,
  btnOnPressed: () async {
    await authCubit.googleSignIn();
  },
  btnColor: const Color(0xffea4335),
  btnText: BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state.socialAuthState
          is SocialAuthSuccess) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    },
    child: FittedBox(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: const [
          Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.google,
            size: 22.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 8.0,
          ),
          Text(
            "Google",
            style: kb3,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Found the Answer

### Step 1 : Get the CLIEND ID from GCP

- We need to have a `clientID` from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
- Click **Create Credentials**
- Click **OAuth Client ID**
- Select application type **Web application** and fill the rest info.

### Step 2: Add CLIENT ID in web/index.html

Add the `clientID` in `web/index.html` with `meta` tag like this:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="someNumberHere-08d5a3p60m4ov8nac9hc96mrknsg68tu.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

### Step 3: Add the CLIENT ID & SECRET ID in Firebase

- Add `clientID` and `clientSecret` in Firebase > Authentication > Sign-in Method

[image]